# Does catching a cold give you an "effective" advantage against future colds?

Tags: immunology, pathology

By effective advantage I mean that if I catch a cold now and then recover fully, does this actually reduce my probability of catching a future cold. I understand that the body can build up anti-bodies and such, but pathogens also have the ability to mutate and I would assume that anti-bodies levels decrease over long periods of time. I am not a biologist! So feel free to correct my poor assumptions.

Thus taking those factors into account, are there models or data to argue that catching a cold gives me a future advantage over avoiding the cold altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

The "cold" is a common term for symptoms caused by dozens of different viruses. Even the canonical "cold" virus (rhinovirus) has large numbers of strains.

Exception to the short answer: Getting a cold might be effective against similar strains of the same virus.

Most of the time, future colds will be due to a different strain or a different virus. Best protection is to block unused/vulnerable receptors in the nose.

Comment: Can you cite something so I can read more? A Wikipedia article or two would be fine.

Comment: Read the "Rhinovirus" and "Common cold" articles on Wikipedia.